# Combobox Add item problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add new item in combobox. But this item should be top in combobox.

For Example;

In my combobox items like; a,b,c,d I want to add e but e is the top.

After adding new item shoukld be -> e,a,b,c,d

How can I do this?

Thanks John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the Insert method of the Items collection of the ComboBox? You should be able to choose the position of the inserted item that way.

```
myComboBox.Items.Insert(0, myItem)
```